# python3 resolve relative import with internal dependency inside module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, grpc-python, relative-import

My folder structure:

```
grpc/
    server.py
    client.py
    ...    
    src/
        __init__.py
        image_pb2.py
        image_pb2_grpc.py 
        ...
```

`server.py`

```
import image_pb2_grpc
import image_pb2

...
```

`image_pb_grpc.py`

```
import image_pb2
...
```

In summary, `server` depends on both `image_pb2` and `image_pb2_grpc`, while `image_pb2_grpc` also depends on `image_pb2`.

Now, if I move my `server.py` inside the `src` folder, the code surely runs fine, as everything is in the path.

The problem is `server.py` should be outside the `src` folder.

Now, I can still solve the problem by changing `server.py` and `image_pb2_grpc.py` with:

`server.py`

```
from src import image_pb2_grpc
from src import image_pb2

...
```

`image_pb_grpc.py`

```
from src import image_pb2
...
```

The issue with this approach is, I need to change `image_pb_grpc.py` manually, as they are generated code from grpc, and they are generated using a bash script, so it is not possible to change them manually.

How can I organize my project so that I can run `server` outside `src`, while not changing `image_pb2` or `image_pb2_grpc`?

Comment: I am not sure, but try `from .src import ...` in `server.py`  and `from . import image_pb2` in  `image_pb_grpc.py`. Also add a empty `__init__.py` to the `src` folder.

Comment: @user_na as I told in my question, I can not change image_pb2 file as it's auto-generated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add to your `src/__init__.py` following code:

```py
import image_pb2_grpc
import image_pb2
```

Then your `server.py` will be able to import those both files simply by:

```
from src import image_pb2_grpc, image_pb2`
```

I haven't tried it but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried it before, didn't work.

Comment: How about changing `PYTHONPATH` to the `src/`?

Comment: I see, I tried `sys.path.append` but it didn't work. But when I do both, `sys.path.append` and importing inside `__init__.py` it works.

Comment: I mean something like that in the shell `$ export PYTHONPATH:=./src`

Comment: But that will be temporary, right? Wouldn't I need to run `export` each time I run `server.py`

Comment: I will work as long your environment (here it's shell) will not get restarted. Even though, you can always add this to the default shell values and it will be always included in the `PYTHONPATH`

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of running your script is:

```
$ cd grpc
$ python -m server # this is the one you want to run
```

Use the relative imports in server.py.

If this does not work I am afraid you need to hack sys.path - but this should be avoided at all cost

EDIT:

In server once you import the `image_pb2` as in `from .src import image_pb2` do

```
sys.modules['image_pb2'] = sys.modules['src.image_pb2']
```

then import image_pb2_grpc. Do not add any imports in `__init__.py`

Comment: This seems like a better option, but I can't seem to get it working. If I cd into the directory, then the `__init__.py` imports fail, and I can't seem to import the libraries.

Comment: What are the `__init__` imports?

Comment: Initially, I solved by importing `image_pb2` and `image_pb2_grpc` inside `src/__init__.py`, and adding `sys.path.append(src path)` inside `server.py`. If I try to run `python3 ../server.py` after `cd`ing into `src`, I get error in the `__init__.py` and `server.py`, saying no module named ...

Comment: You should cd into parent dir not src.

Comment: Then you need some hacks in src probably